# Inserting an object in a JavaScript file into mongo

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have an object that I created in a JavaScript file that essentially looks like this.

```
{ name1:
     {'category 1'  : {'stat1': 1, 'stat 2': 1},
      'category 2'  : {'stat1': 1, 'stat 2': 1}},
  name2...}
```

And I want to insert this object into my database in mongo. The error I'm getting is

```
Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb
```

which points to this line in my code.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db){
    if (err)...
    else{
        var collection = db.collection("mydb");
        //this function is giving an error
        collection.insert(myObj, function(err, result) {
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        else...
```

I suspect it may be because my object is in an incompatible format for mongo to handle, in which case my question is how to convert it into a usable format?

Answer (score 0):

If you head over to [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

you'll find that your object isn't a valid JSON Object.

To create a valid JSON Object you can do this :

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.name1 = {};
myObj.name1.category1 = {};
myObj.name1.category1.stat1 = 1;
myObj.name1.category1.stat2 = 1;
myObj.name1.category2 = {};
myObj.name1.category2.stat1 = 1;
myObj.name1.category2.stat2 = 1;
```

Ideally name1 object should be an array which then should contain category1 & category2 objects as elements of the array. Also myObj should also be an array that should then contain name1 and name2 objects as element. Then you can use MongoDB's insertMany function to insert the array.

So say you have the array as :

```
var myObjs = [];
var obj1 = {};
obj1.name1 = {};
obj1.name1.category1 = {};
obj1.name1.category1.stat1 = 1;
obj1.name1.category1.stat2 = 1;
obj1.name1.category2 = {};
obj1.name1.category2.stat1 = 1;
obj1.name1.category2.stat2 = 1;
myObjs.push(obj1);
collection.insertMany(myObjs, function(err, result){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('Documents inserted successfully');
});
```

Just always make sure that your object is a valid JSON Object before inserting.

Answer (score -2):

you should be using insertOne instead of insert 
https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/insert/